# Multi page site with link in a section

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a site where i have more than 1 page. I have a navbar like this

```html
    <nav class="navbar">
    
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="Ricette.html">Ricette</a>
      <a href="#foto">Foto</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
```

I want link the page "ricette" with the section "about" that is on the homepage.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more to clarify the question?

Comment: `ricette.html#about`?

Comment: ricette.html#about this works. Thx a lot

Answer (score -1):

I think your are creating one page site, so you have to create Home, About, Ricette, Foto, Contact sections in index.html page, after that, assign id to each section in html

Example

```
<section id="home">...</section>
<section id="about">...</section>

.
.
.
and so on.
```

I think this will be for you.

Comment: `I'm creating a site where i have more than 1 page...` -> doesn't sound like a SPA to me. Not minding that you miss the question (which is very vague I admit).

Comment: then you can add link <a href="./about.html">About</a>

Comment: yeah, my bad. My eng is pretty bad and is hard to explain what i mean, i will try. I have a nab bar top whit some link. The frist 2 link are on the frist page while the 3 is a new page. I wanna link the 3 navbar link whit the 2 section on the main page

Comment: You can add Link with <a> tag,

if you want to link to section on other pages then you can do that

<a href="./about.html#secion1">About Us<a>
<a href="./contact.html#section2">Contact Us</a>

I hope you get it, otherwise you can hire me on fiverr : mernweb

Answer (score -1):

The code should work

```html
    <nav class="navbar">
    
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#about">Ricette</a>
      <a href="#foto">Foto</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> //These <br>s are for showing how code works.
    <div id="about">Hello</div>
```

Comment: why tons of `<br>` if you need spacings then use margins... also the question is very vague, but I doubt that his issue is to link to an ID when he uses in 4 other links within the same code.

Comment: That was an example for the code to work... I wanted to show how it works